# "Happen not to" something

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have seen the below sentence and I want to know what exactly **"happen not to something"** means. Is it an idiom or there is a grammatical rule for that?

> ...because we happen not to have seen it in our training text...

Answer (score 0):

It suggests that the event in question (in this case, not seeing something in the training text) was unintentional, occurred by chance, and implies that the event was unlikely.

Another example:

> I happened to see Claire at the grocery store.

You could just as easily say "I saw Claire at the grocery store", but the first sentence emphasizes that it was a coincidence. On the other hand, if Claire worked at the grocery store in an area where she was likely to be seen by customers, it would not be so odd to see her there and so I would use the second sentence.